# Camunda BPMN Fails on Execution due to Value too long for column TEXT_ VARCHAR(4000)

Tags: kotlin, camunda, bpmn

I read that in order to bypass this limitation, I could save the BPMN definition as an Object so Camunda treats and stores it differently.

I could also change the Client side to send the definition in a format other than a string and modify the API endpoint to treat it accordingly.

I haven't been able to find any examples or references on how to achieve this, I'm using Kotlin by the way.

In my `/startExecution` API, I start the execution with:

```
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(existingWorkflowMetadata.id)
```

As you can see, I'm not passing any process variables here. The variable that causes the error to occur is passed to Camunda, at an earlier stage:

We first get our definition from the Client, when it hits our `/createWorkflow` API –one of the required parameters is `definition` which is treated as a String, we use it to create our `modelInstance` like this:

```
val modelInstance = parseBpmn(request.definition)
```

Then, we pass this `modelInstance` to Camunda with:

```
repositoryService.createDeployment()
.tenantId(tenantId) 
.addModelInstance(UID, modelInstance)
.deploy()
```

This whole process succeeds, but when the Client hits `/startExecution`, it fails with:

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error.",
  "exceptionStackTrace": 
  "org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-03004 
  Exception while executing Database Operation 'INSERT 
  HistoricVariableInstanceEntity[97cc9204-256e-11ed-9d56- 
  0242244cf691]' with message '\n### Error flushing statements.  
  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: 
  org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity
 .HistoricVariableInstanceEntity.insertHistoricVariableInstance 
 (batch index #1) failed. Cause: 
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Value too long for column 
 \"TEXT_ VARCHAR(4000)\": \"'{\"\"displayName\"\":\"\"mx_ 
 [contiues...] 
 }
```

---

### @rob2universe suggested me to create an object:

```
ObjectValue objValue = Variables
.objectValue(myJavaObject)
.serializationDataFormat(Variables.SerializationDataFormats.JSON)
.create();
```

Then add it to a map and pass it to the `startProcessInstanceByKey`:

```
 runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(UID, myMap)
```

But I have a few questions:

1. What is `myJavaObject`, is it my `modelInstance` or the definition value I get from the client (a String)?
2. As I mentioned above, the `definition` variable that causes the error is being passed to Camunda when the Client hits `/createWorkflow` and we do `repositoryService.createDeployment().tenantId(tenantId).addModelInstance(UID, modelInstance).deploy()` but the error occurs when the Client hits `/startExecution` and we start the process with
   `runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(UID)`

Should I stop passing this variable through the `repositoryService` and instead just pass it through the map as you suggest?:

```
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(UID,myMap)
```

Answer (score 2):

See: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/process-engine/variables/

For example, create a JSON object like this:

```
 ObjectValue objValue = Variables
          .objectValue(myJavaObject)
          .serializationDataFormat(Variables.SerializationDataFormats.JSON)
          .create();
```

Then add it to a Map, which gets passed in at process start:
https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.17/org/camunda/bpm/engine/RuntimeService.html#startProcessInstanceByKey(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Map)

For JSON (or XML) to be supported, which you should prefer over Java serialization, you need to have SPIN in the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>camunda-engine-plugin-spin</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.camunda.spin</groupId>
  <artifactId>camunda-spin-dataformat-all</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

myJavaObject is a Java POJO you work with, e.g. the customer or account or whatever process data you work with.

Separate the deployment step from starting the instance. At first you are deploying a model instance, which seems to succeed and not cause the DB error. After this complete the model has been written to the DB. So lets exclude the model deployment from the analysis for now.

Next you are starting a process instance using the process definition key. As part of the process execution something is writing process data, which is a too long String. If you are not sending in this process data at process start, then maybe it gets created as part of you subsequent task. A data mapping, a task listener, a Java Delegate, an external worker, an expression,... many things could be creating this data. Check where the process is creating large process data.

Comment: could you elaborate more on why JSON or XML should be preferred over Java serialization, in the context of Camunda.

Comment: Added a bit more context and follow up questions for you, rob!

Comment: Java Serialization is deprecated. It creates tight coupling as the client also needs to have the classes available. Also versioning of serializable Java classes is not as easy to handle as JSON. Most payload nowadays are JSON, so it also make sense to store objects this way. On json you can easily use jsonPath. Json is a text fromat and can be read immediately when using XML. Json to java serialization is simple

Comment: Added to answer. You can also simplify your model to a a dummy step and test.